# pickle doesn't work in compile/exec

Tags: python, pickle

I want to use pickle in compile/exec, but it doesn't work for me. It only works when I use the global namespace. But I don't want to use global namespace, is there any way for that ? Thanks

```
>>> a = compile("def f():\n\t'hello'\nimport pickle\npickle.dumps(f)", "<stdin>", "exec")
>>> exec(a)            # works
>>> exec(a, {})        # fails  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function f at 0x1050881e0>: it's not the same object as __main__.f
>>> exec(a, {'__name__': '__main__'})   # fails too
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function f at 0x1050882f0>: it's not the same object as __main__.f
```

Comment: `dill` pickles functions and should work.

Comment: @tdelaney sorry I don't get it, can you explain more ? Thanks

Comment: `pickle` saves textual names of functions but not function objects themselves.  An unpickler needs to import the module to get the function. In your first case you bound the function to the global namespace of a top level script. That namespace is called `__main__` so all you did was pickle instructions to load a module called `__main__` and use its `f` function. Since neither `__main__` nor `f` can be found, it couldn't work. `dill` pickles functions themselves and has a better chance of working for you.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do this (nothing reasonable anyway). Functions pickle by qualified name, they don't actually pickle any part of their implementation. They unpickle by simply importing the module they were defined in and loading the name in question. If there is no namespace to find the function on (you replaced the globals of `__main__` with your own custom `dict` that has no ties to `__main__`'s globals), you can't `pickle` it, because `__main__.f` (the qualified name of `f`) doesn't exist in the globals of `__main__`.

Comment: Is there anyway to define module in compile/exec ?

Comment: @zjffdu: If you pass the globals of an imported module into `exec`, it will behave as if defined there. So, for example, `import os`, then `exec(a, vars(os))` would work, because `f` would actually be defined on the `os` module, with a qualified name of `os.f`, so it could be pickled (it just couldn't be unpickled by anyone who hadn't attached a function named `f` to the `os` module to match).